# How to display all output in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I am learning using RandomSearchCV to find best parameters for Random Forest Classifier on Jupyter notebook.

I used a pipeline + standard scaler.

```
steps = [('scaler',StandardScaler()),('clf',RandomForestClassifier())]
RF = Pipeline(steps)

RF_params = {'clf__n_estimators':np.arange(50,150,10),'clf__criterion': 
['gini','entropy'],\
'clf__max_depth':[2,3,4,5]}

random_R = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=RF,param_distributions=RF_params,\
                         n_iter=20,cv=3,verbose=1,scoring='f1')

random_R.fit(train,y)
```

Then I used
    random_R.best_estimator_ 
and 
    random_R.get_params
to output results, but it only showed:

```
Pipeline(memory=None,
 steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True)), ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
        max_depth=3, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
        min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
    ...obs=None,
        oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
        warm_start=False))])
```

Most output was omitted. Is there a way to display all output? I googled this and tried to change notebook's output setting but it did not work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

in your output try adding

```html
,mode = 'a'
```

it sounds like instead of appending it is overwriting.  Check out the documentation here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html

Comment: Thanks for answering my question Sara, but I still could not display everything. I just found that the output can be displayed 100% if I separate scaler and random search (not using pipeline). But this is really awkward.